# This computer dont support Intel Virtualization HAMX cannot be installed

Tags: android, intel

I get the following error

[image]

My procesator is AMD is supported for intel

I´ve got enable in the bios virtualization

What´s the problem?

[image]

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I try a install skd since terminal Visual Studio

```
C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager>intelhaxm-android.exe
```

I dont found the route in my physical computer. I can only from my terminal visual studio, execute intelhaxm-android.exe

I´ve enabled vt-x in my amd

[image]
Any for fix my problem and I can run the emulator? Thanks

Comment: Update ADT and then update SDK! Make sure that there versions are same.

Comment: But an `AMD` is not an `Intel` processor. Why would `Intel` add support for their competitor in the `Intel HAXM`? What I'm getting at: it's not possible to use Intel HAXM with AMD. Where did you read that AMD support Intel's VT?

Comment: Looks like you won't be able to use HAXM with your hardware, but you can try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) instead.

Comment: Is there any virtualization option in your BIOS page?

Comment: Yes, I have it active

Comment: @MiguelAnguloMartínez what's the name of the virtualization option in your BIOS? If it's called AMD-v, then it's still not Intel VT and won't work...

Comment: I've the same Problem right now , Have you solved yours?

Answer (score 0):

check whether  you have installed HAXM installer on your SDK Manager. It is located in

```
{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe
```